# Phrase about increasing effect

Tags: meaning

I would like to get some opinions on this:

*The more hours you put into your work, the more tasks you are able to handle, and ultimately, the greater your advantage becomes towards your competition.*

My question involves the last part of the sentence: "the greater your advantage becomes towards your competition."

Is there a better way to put this?

Comment: Please see also [writers.se]

Answer (score 2):

The more usual way of phrasing that would be

> the greater your advantage over your competition.

I've never heard of an advantage *towards* anything; it's always *over* in my experience.